# how solve below issue with out key word?

Tags: c#

here i am putting some example just like i am facing problem now with my code..
here i have to use reference types only in my code.

```
namespace Outissue
{
    class Program
    {
        static int Method(out  int i, out int j, out int k)
        {
            i = 44;
            j = 55;
            k = 67;
            int d = i + j + k;
            return d;

        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int total, a ,b,c;
            a = 100;
            b = 200;
            c = 300;
            total = Method(out a,out  b, out  c);
            Console.WriteLine(total);
        }
    }
}
```

here the method have to print the result of  600 as total. The problem is out keyword is initialization. in my  application ref is not recommended , so i should go with out keyword only..

is there any alternative way other than out keyword but it have to behave just like "ref or out"

note: not supposed to use ref keyword
can you please help me out from this?

Comment: If you already have what you want, then why would you need something else to serve the same purpose!!!! "out" is doing what it supposed to do. "here the method have to print the result of 600 as total" why????

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve. You change the values inside `Method` and add them up, how do you expect it to be 600? Also in your code you don't need `out` at all.

Comment: @AshadShanto I guess it is a homework.

Comment: Are you sure you are clear about what you want??

Comment: Once you create the Tuple, we cannot change the values of its fields. here my requirement is not about the values we can pass any thing from any where values may change. the add calculation have to take the incoming values

Comment: in my case i am facing the problem with ref key word . i thought that ref can replaced with out , I don't know it may wrong.

Comment: @shivaA "out" is like the "ref" keyword, except that "ref" requires that the variable be initialized before it is passed.

out : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx   ref :  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If this is a homework assignment, I think you have misunderstood.

What you have written, regardless of the out keyword or the ref keyword, will always return a total of 166, because you change the values of the *local variables* in your method called Method().

If they are asking you to understand what the ref keyword and out keywords do, then I recommend that you read this http://www.dotnetperls.com/parameter and write an example that shows the difference between when you use ref, when you use out and when you use neither.

Answer (score 0):

out parameters do not have to be initialized before being passed, the called method is required to assign a value before the method returns.

```
namespace Outissue
{
    class Program
    {
        static int Method(out  int i, out int j, out int k)
        {
            i = 100;
            j = 200;
            k = 300;
            int d = i + j + k;
            return d;

        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int total, a ,b,c;
            total = Method(out a,out  b, out  c);
            Console.WriteLine(total);
        }
    }
}
```